# How to check existence of a value in between two columns of the same table

Tags: mysql, exists

I have a table **bills** having columns  `id, starting_bl_no, ending_bl_no`.

How can I check a new bill number input is already exist in the table?

```
id    starting_bl_no    ending_bl_no    
 1     100              140  
 2     357              500  
 3     150              190
```

**Note**: ie, if the input is **102** I should return exists. Or if the input is **145** should return not exists

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 `Does It Interfere?`
FROM table
WHERE @newBillNumber BETWEEN starting_bl_no AND ending_bl_no
```